# How to achieve Database Synchronization in Adobe Air with out LCDS

Tags: air

i designed one application which pulls data from DB once its stated,if all the clients pulls data at a time from server, there is a lot of bandwidth, and one more worse case is one client may close & open his application many time a days, so there is a lot of bandwidth consumption on serve...

Is there any database Sync technique to implement in AIR desktop application ?
Please if anybody know please let me know..plz dont suggest LCDS(this is bit cost)

Advance Thanking,

Cheers,
vasu

Answer (score 0):

Try and go for GraniteDS